# Grouping of XML with a twist

Tags: xml, xslt

I was trying doing some grouping in XSL. Was being able to do some as well. Where it checks the SuperParent and search all the same SuperParent block and group them together. The transformation can be found here: [Grouping by Super Parent](http://xsltransform.net/jxN8Npv/1)

But wondering if we can do something like the below, where I need a way to show the Date, SuperParent, Id & Phase at the same level as element only where the SuperParent and the Id are same.

Input:

```
<response status="200">
<ElementList>
    <Element>
        <Date>2017-12-18</Date>
        <SuperParent>1462682</SuperParent>
        <Id>1462682</Id>
        <Status>Completed</Status>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <Date>2017-12-16</Date>
        <SuperParent>1462682</SuperParent>
        <Id>1462683</Id>
        <Status>Normal</Status>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <Date>2017-12-15</Date>
        <SuperParent>1462682</SuperParent>
        <Id>1462687</Id>
        <Status>Normal</Status>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <Date>2017-12-19</Date>
        <SuperParent>1462812</SuperParent>
        <Id>1462812</Id>
        <Status>Normal</Status>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <Date>2017-12-18</Date>
        <SuperParent>1462812</SuperParent>
        <Id>1462813</Id>
        <Status>Normal</Status>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <Date>2017-12-17</Date>
        <SuperParent>1462812</SuperParent>
        <Id>1462817</Id>
        <Status>Normal</Status>
    </Element>
</ElementList>
```

Required output:

```
<ElementList>
<superparent id="1462682">
    <Date>2017-12-18</Date>
    <SuperParent>1462682</SuperParent>
    <Id>1462682</Id>
    <Status>Completed</Status>
    <element>
        <SuperParent>1462682</SuperParent>
        <Id>1462683</Id>
        <Status>Normal</Status>
    </element>
    <element>
        <SuperParent>1462682</SuperParent>
        <Id>1462687</Id>
        <Status>Normal</Status>
    </element>
</superparent>

<superparent id="1462812">
    <Date>2017-12-19</Date>
    <SuperParent>1462812</SuperParent>
    <Id>1462812</Id>
    <Status>Normal</Status>
    <element>
        <SuperParent>1462812</SuperParent>
        <Id>1462813</Id>
        <Status>Normal</Status>
    </element>
    <element>
        <SuperParent>1462812</SuperParent>
        <Id>1462817</Id>
        <Status>Normal</Status>
    </element>
</superparent>
```

Adding the xsltransform.net XSLT, as requested.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="groupBySuperParent" match="Element" use="SuperParent"/>
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <ElementList>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ElementList>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match= "Element[generate-id()=generate-id(key('groupBySuperParent',SuperParent)[1])]">
    <superparent id="{SuperParent}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('groupBySuperParent',SuperParent)"/>
    </superparent>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match= "Element[not(generate-id()=generate-id(key('groupBySuperParent',SuperParent)[1]))]"/>
```

Which gives the below output:

```
<ElementList>
<superparent id="1462682">
    <Element>
        <Date>2017-12-18</Date>
        <SuperParent>1462682</SuperParent>
        <Id>1462682</Id>
        <Phase>Completed</Phase>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <Date>2017-12-16</Date>
        <SuperParent>1462682</SuperParent>
        <Id>1462683</Id>
        <Status>Normal</Status>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <Date>2017-12-15</Date>
        <SuperParent>1462682</SuperParent>
        <Id>1462687</Id>
        <Status>Normal</Status>
    </Element>
</superparent>
<superparent id="1462812">
    <Element>
        <Date>2017-12-19</Date>
        <SuperParent>1462812</SuperParent>
        <Id>1462812</Id>
        <Status>Normal</Status>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <Date>2017-12-18</Date>
        <SuperParent>1462812</SuperParent>
        <Id>1462813</Id>
        <Status>Normal</Status>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <Date>2017-12-17</Date>
        <SuperParent>1462812</SuperParent>
        <Id>1462817</Id>
        <Status>Normal</Status>
    </Element>
</superparent>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the XSLT. xsltransform.net is useful, but does tend to become unavailable frequently. Thanks!

Comment: Added the XSL, Tim C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Muenchian Grouping with an `xsl:for-each`, leaving out the first positional *Element* node and any non *Date* child nodes. Also be sure to include `<xsl:strip-space element="*"/>` to remove saved line breaks/spaces from source XML.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="groupBySuperParent" match="Element" use="SuperParent"/>

    <xsl:template match="/response/*">
        <ElementList>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Element[generate-id()=generate-id(key('groupBySuperParent',SuperParent)[1])]"/>
        </ElementList>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match= "Element">
        <superparent id="{SuperParent}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="*[name()!='Date']"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('groupBySuperParent',SuperParent)">
                    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
                        <element>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="*[name()!='Date']"/>
                        </element>  
                    </xsl:if>                   
                </xsl:for-each>         
        </superparent>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[XSLTransform.Net Demo](http://xsltransform.net/nb9MWsx)

Answer (score 1):

You can group as before but then you need to make sure you select and process the elements in each group based on that condition between Id and SuperParent:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="groupBySuperParent" match="Element" use="SuperParent"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <ElementList>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ElementList>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match= "Element[generate-id()=generate-id(key('groupBySuperParent', SuperParent)[1])]">
    <superparent id="{SuperParent}">
        <xsl:variable name="group" select="key('groupBySuperParent', SuperParent)"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$group[Id = SuperParent]/Date | $group[Id = SuperParent]/SuperParent | $group[Id = SuperParent]/Id | $group[Id = SuperParent]/Phase"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$group[not(Id = SuperParent)]" mode="change"/>
    </superparent>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Element[not(generate-id()=generate-id(key('groupBySuperParent', SuperParent)[1]))]"/>

<xsl:template match="Element" mode="change">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="SuperParent | Id | Status"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e29/2

Comment: Thanks for this. But could you have a look here http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5b Not sure why the 1st block (the -1 one) is getting repeated.

Comment: @Sierra, I don't see any condition in your linked sample to make sure the elements with `ParentRequestId` as `-1` or with the same `RequestId` and `SuperParentRequestId` are not transformed by the `apply-templates`.

Comment: Silly me. Copy paste mistake. Thanks for your answer.